# Calculating day of year from date

Tags: c++

I need to calculate the day number of a given date. The year has 366 days in it. Each month however has a different value and I have to assign the values. Is there a quicker way to do it rather than the way I am going about it?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   int day, month, year, dayNumber;

   cout<< "Please enter the month, by numerical value:";
   cin>> month;
   cout<<"Please enter the day, by numerical value:";
   cin>> day;
   cout<<"Please enter the year, by numerical value:";
   cin>> year;
   if (month == 1)
   {
      dayNumber= day;
      cout<< "Month;" << '\t'<< month << '\n'
          << "Day:"<<'\t'<< day<< '\n'
          << "Year:"<<'\t'<< year<<'\n'
          << "Day Number:"<< '\t'<< dayNumber<< endl;
   }
   else if(month==2)
   {
      dayNumber= day+31; 
   }
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: Is this a learning exercise, or is it needed for a real-world solution? If the latter then the time.h runtime library will do what you want very efficiently. See answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many ways it is probably best to avoid hand-rolling this.

Use boost:

```
#include <boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp>

//...
try {
    boost::gregorian::date d(year, month, day);
    dayNumber = d.day_of_year();
}
catch (std::out_of_range& e) {
    // Alternatively catch bad_year etc exceptions.
    std::cout << "Bad date: " << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

As James Kanze suggests you could also use mktime to avoid dependency on boost (untested):

```
  tm timeinfo = {};
  timeinfo.tm_year = year - 1900;
  timeinfo.tm_mon = month - 1;
  timeinfo.tm_mday = day;
  mktime(&timeinfo);
  dayNumber = timeinfo.tm_yday;
```

Comment: You don't need Boost; `mktime` is part of the standard library (and supposes a Gregorian calendar).

Comment: @JamesKanze thats useful - added to the answer

Comment: Re `timeinfo`: you don't need the `struct` keyword; that's just a C'ism.  And you should really initialize it when it is declared: `tm timeinfo = {};`, and skip the `memset`.

Comment: @JamesKanze ok changed that, the struct part was copy/paste from a c++ reference site - just laziness on my part..

Answer (score 9):

Just use `mktime`:

```
tm date = {};
date.tm_year = year - 1900;
date.tm_mon = month - 1;
date.tm_mday = day;
mktime( &date );
dayNumber = date.tm_yday;
```

Otherwise, you'll need a two dimensional table:

```
int daysToMonth[2][12] =
{
    { 0, 31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334 },
    { 0, 31, 60, 91, 121, 152, 182, 213, 244, 274, 305, 335 },
};
```

and a function:

```
bool isLeapYear( int year )
{
    return year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0);
}
```

The year day is then:

```
daysToMonth[isLeapYear( year ) ? 1 : 0][month] + day;
```

Comment: No need for `? 1 : 0`, the boolean values `true` and `false` are guaranteed by C++ to be `1` and `0` when used in a numeric context.

Comment: @MarkRansom Certainly.  But implicit conversions like that just make code unreadable, and should be avoided.

Answer (score 4):

First you need to know if the year is a leap year or not :

```
bool isLeap(year) {
    return (((year % 4) == 0) && (((year % 100) != 0) || ((year % 400) == 0))
}
```

Then you could create, for given year and array or day-per-month number :

```
unsigned int daysPerMonth[] = {31, (isLeap(year) ? 29 : 28), 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
```

I only give you chunks of code, but they may help you.

Loop through this array to get the real day number. By an example April 4th 1989, not leap year. It's The number of days 31+28+31 (for January to March) then +4.

Comment: That means recreating (and initializing) the array each time (plus a loop).  Use two arrays, one for leap year, one for the non-leap years.  And put the cumulative values in the array.

Comment: That was just an illustrative example :)

Comment: @JamesKanze : actually no arrays should ever be created, period. See my solution below.

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto It's certainly possible to do it without an array. But it's much simpler and easier to understand using static arrays. But static arrays result in much more readable (and probably faster) code. Why be complicated when there is a simple solution.

Comment: @JamesKanze : and that's yet another item to review regarding typos, even though the any month not named February is nothing more than `30 + (a 1/0 flag for whether months before august are odd-numbered, and even on or afterwards - something you can literally do a `xor` over those 2 items, mathematically speaking), like literally just `function longmonth(_) { return xor(_ % 2, 7 < +_)
} function shortmonth(_) { return xor(_ % 2, +_ < 8) }` (assuming inputs are already in-range) ::::::::::: or even just `function shortmonth(_) { return 7<_~_%2 }  ` for the shortest code I could conjure up

Comment: @JamesKanze : so a num days function becomes just ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::  `function days_in_month(m, leap) { return 28 + (m != 2 ? ((m < 8) == m % 2) + 2 : leap) }` ::::: the entire function only has combos of `2`s and `8`s (excuse the ugly formatting of it - i just slapped it together)…………… to phrase it another way - allocate 28 days base, add 2 more whenever it's not February, and add 1 more for either long month of Feb in leap-year.

Comment: @JamesKanze : but **this** one I'm most proud of :: `function date2julian(__, ____, ___, _) { return (_ += _^= _<_) < __-- ? ____ + (___ == "" ? ___ : ! ( (___ = +___) % (_+_)^_^! (___ % (___ = _+_+!!_)^_) ) ) - (__ <= (_ += ++_)) + _*(__ *= ___) + int(__/ (_+_)) : (____ -= __) + _^_^_ * (__ + __) }` :::: a strictly `POSIX-compliant` and fully standalone function, without any lookup arrays/strins, can calculate exact ordinal date of year, for given `mm, dd, yy (opt)`, and works for negative years too, …..

Comment: …… since that code already includes leap-year calc, **plus** ordinal-"julian" date calc. dfting to common yr cuz casting empty string to integer gets back a zero, and Year-0 is leap, which might not be an expected outcome from leaving year-field out blank. But it also could distinguish an actual input of year-0. Only downside of it having no input range validity checks. `date2julian(10, 21, 2023) —> 294`. `9 29 9007199254740881 —> 272` - Sept 29 of that future year much older than doubling universe's entire age would still be ordinal-julian date of 272, since it's common year

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto The one you're most proud of is pretty cool (although I think it's missing a ';' after the expression in the `return`). A worthy candidate for the IOCCC.

Comment: @JamesKanze : how so ? `jot -w '%d 1 2019' 12 | mawk '1;++$NF' | gsort -k 3,3n -k 1,1n | awk 'function date2julian(__, ____, ___, _) { return (_ += _^= _<_) < __-- ? ____ + (___ == "" ? ___ : ! ( (___ = +___) % (_+_)^_^! (___ % (___ = _+_+!!_)^_) ) ) - (__ <= (_ += ++_)) + _*(__ *= ___) + int(__/ (_+_)) : (____ -= __) + _^_^_ * (__ + __) } ($++NF = date2julian($1,$2,$3))^_'` ::::: it gave back same correct results for `gawk`, `mawk`, and `nawk`

Comment: @JamesKanze : oh sorry should've clarified - the function i posted was `awk` code not `C` or `C++`, and those `^` operators are exponentiation not bit-wise XOR

Answer (score 1):

You could create a vector containing the numbers of days in each month:

```
std::vector<int> days_in_month;
days_in_month.push_back(31); //Jan
days_in_month.push_back(29); //Feb
... // so on for each month
```

Then, to calculate, you could do this:

```
int day = <day_entered_by_user>;
int month = <month_entered_by_user>;

int num_of_days = 0;
// Sum the number of days for all months preceding the current month
for(int i = 0; i < (month - 1); ++i)
  num_of_days += days_in_month[i];

// Finally just add the day entered for the current month
num_of_days += day;
```

Comment: That's a really cool way of doing it. We haven't even begun to talk about vectors though so I would never have thought to do that.

Comment: Why be simple when you can be complicated.  I could see `std::array`, if you really wanted, but this is one time where the C style arrays are preferable.

Comment: @JamesKanze Unless there's a very strong reason to do so, I wouldn't induce a C-ism into C++. std::array is probably the ideal way to go here.

Comment: @Nikhil In this case, it probably doesn't matter one way or the other.  `std::array` has the advantage of being a full fledged type (copyable, etc.), but I can't imagine doing anything here where that would matter.  C style arrays have the advantage that you don't have to state the size; the compiler will count the initializers, but in this case, you clearly want a size of 12.  More generally, `std::array` requires C++11, which means it may not be an option.  And most of the time you're not using `std::vector`, the compiler will be counting the initializers, so `std::array` is out.

Comment: @JamesKanze do you immediately see if there are exactly 12 values? No you don't, you'd have to actually count them (there's research showing that every number of objects greater than roughly 6 items is not immediately estimable). Can bullshit happen if you accidentally don't provide enough values? Yes _it most like will happen_. `std::array` takes this away with no actual cost. `std::array` is the way to go.

Comment: @stefan There is exactly no difference between C style arrays and `std::array` with regards to the initialization here.  I don't see what you're claiming.  Whether I write `std::array<std::array<int, 12>, 2> days = { { ... }, { ... }};` or `int  days[2][12] = ...;`, the risks are exactly the same.

Comment: @JamesKanze may I remember you of your own statement: "C style arrays have the advantage that you don't have to state the size". That's a stupid idea to count that as an advantage over `std::array`, because of easily made mistakes. See my last comment..

Comment: It's not an advantage here, as I specifically said: we need exactly 12 months.  It _is_ an advantage, and a great one, in many other cases, where you have a list of initializers (which can change), and having to count them and specify the size would introduce an additional source of errors.

Answer (score 1):

really short code will look like follwoing:

```
{
    int nonleap[12]={0,31, 31+28, 31+28+31, 31+28+31+30 .....};
    int leap[12]={0,31, 31+29, 31+29+31, 31+29+31+30 .....};

    if(yearIsLeap(year))
       return leap[month]+day;
    else
       return nonleap[month]+day;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the number of days per month in an array:

```
int days_per_month[] = {31, 29, 31, ...};
```

or

```
std::array<int, 12> days_per_month{{31, 29, 31,...}};
```

Then you need to loop over that array to calculate the sum of already passed days:

```
int sum = 0;
for ( int i = 1; i < month; ++i )
{
    sum += days_per_month[i - 1]; // note the index shift!
}
dayNumber += sum;
```

Another alternative is to directly store the sums in the array:

```
std::array<int, 12> passed_days{{0, 31, 60,...}};
```

Then you get rid of the loop:

```
dayNumber += passed_days[month - 1];
```

For leap years, simply check for the year and if the month is at least 3.

Comment: Doesn't take into account leap years.

Comment: And is unnecessarily inefficient; there's absolutely no need for a loop here.

Comment: @JamesKanze Well why do you think do i include a loop-free alternative? For exactly that reason. I do prefer the loop though. It expresses what's actually happening. Personally I'd be confused by an array holding the sums of days as these are unusual numbers for any human beeing.

Answer (score 0):

You guys are making this really difficult, why not just roll up the first 2 answers

```
int year = 2020, month = 12, day = 10;

tm timeinfo = {};
int dayNumber = 0;

bool isLeap = (((year % 4) == 0) && (((year % 100) != 0) || ((year % 400) == 0));

timeinfo.tm_year = year - 1900;
timeinfo.tm_mon = month - 1;
timeinfo.tm_mday = day;
mktime(&timeinfo);
dayNumber = timeinfo.tm_yday;
if (isLeap && month > 2) dayNumber++;
```

Answer (score 0):

you actually don't need a hard-coded lookup table at all. (this code is `awk` but the algorithm is generic enough it's easily portable) :

---

```
# gawk profile, created Sat Jul 29 19:46:36 2023

# Rule(s)

24  ($++NF = mm2ddd($3, $2))^_

# Functions, listed alphabetically

24  function mm2ddd(__, _) {
        
       #  __|<--  month-# input, integer, 
       #          auto-clamped to [1, 12], inclusive
      ###
       #   _|<--  leap-year flag/indicator (opt.)
       #          auto-scanned both numerically and by regex
      ###      
       #    | --> day-of-year at end of month-# [__]
       #          aka "julian-(ordinal)-date"
       #
       #             [31, 365]:= common years
       #             [31, 366]:=  leap  years
     
24      return \
        ((_ = !!+_ || _ ~ "^([Yy]([Ee][Ss])?|[Ll]([Ee][Aa][Pp])?|29|366)$" \
           ) - ((__ += (__ %= (_ += _^=_) * (_ += _+_)) <= -__ ? _+_ : \
         !_) <= _))^(!!_ < __) + __ * _ * --_ + int(__ * _ / (++_ + _))
    }
```

---

```
|   Common  |   1   |   31
|   Common  |   2   |   59
|   Common  |   3   |   90
|   Common  |   4   |   120

|   Common  |   5   |   151
|   Common  |   6   |   181
|   Common  |   7   |   212
|   Common  |   8   |   243

|   Common  |   9   |   273
|   Common  |   10  |   304
|   Common  |   11  |   334
|   Common  |   12  |   365
```

---

```
|   LEAP    |   1   |   31
|   LEAP    |   2   |   60
|   LEAP    |   3   |   91
|   LEAP    |   4   |   121

|   LEAP    |   5   |   152
|   LEAP    |   6   |   182
|   LEAP    |   7   |   213
|   LEAP    |   8   |   244

|   LEAP    |   9   |   274
|   LEAP    |   10  |   305
```

> ***`LEAP   |   11  |   335`***

```
|   LEAP    |   12  |   366
```

I randomly stumbled upon this relationship between the date-value components :

```
            ( month-# * 30 days )  # base-case
   
    + ( 1/0 indicator for either January or LEAP year )
              
    - ( 1/0 indicator for February through June,
                      which can be expressed as
         
        ( 4 - month-# ) ^ 2 <= 4 ) 

    +  floor( month-#  *  5 / 11 )

   ---------------------------------------------
   
    ==> month-end julian-ordinal date
```

---

That `5 / 11` ratio may appear arbitrary at first,

```
         30 + ( 5 / 11 )
  
    = ( 330 +  5 ) / 11

    =   335  /  11
```

`335 days` just so happens to be the month-end ordinal date value for **November (11)** in a leap year -

> The algorithm is essentially performing floating point interpolation with a leap'ed November as it's frame of reference, plus adjustment factors that combine effects of long-short months against leap-year peculiarities (but not identical to the leap-year formula itself).

It assumes a [proleptic Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proleptic_Gregorian_calendar)
|

- For completeness, here are the pre-floored `5 / 11` ratios for all months ::

  ```
    0.45454545454545454545
    0.90909090909090909090
    1.36363636363636363636

    1.81818181818181818181
    2.27272727272727272727
    2.72727272727272727272

    3.18181818181818181818
    3.63636363636363636363
    4.09090909090909090909

    4.54545454545454545454
    5.00000000000000000000
    5.45454545454545454545
  ```

Yes I technically could've simplified it into what I consider to be

> *some random arbitrary adjustment factor just to make the equation work*

```
  floor( ( month-# - 1 ) / 2 )
```

thus likely confounding correlation with causation.

Answer (score 0):

C++20 version:

```
#include <chrono>

int
day_of_year(int y, int m, int d)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    return (sys_days{year{y}/m/d} - sys_days{year{y}/1/0}).count();
}
```

Notes:

1. This makes Jan 1 day 1, as opposed to day 0, consistent with the code in the question.  Note that `tm_yday` makes Jan 1 day 0.  If `tm_yday` semantics is desired, just change `year{y}/1/0` to `year{y}/1/1`.
2. Source code is concise and easy to reason about. No tables of days in months.
3. Generated assembly is efficient: [demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/zK1rdzW9s).  gcc manages short, branchless, user-space code.
4. No need to consult the locally set time zone as the `mktime` solution must do.
5. Yes, gets the right answer for leap years.
6. Guaranteed to work for the proleptic Gregorian calendar in the range -32,767-01-01 to 32,767-12-31 (+/-32 thousand years).  The `mktime` on my platform only goes back to 1900-01-01.
7. No dependence on external library.